# In T-SQL What is the best way to handle groups within groups?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This issue is from a booking system, the task is to add a flag to the table and also produce total number of visitors.

| ItineraryID | BookingID | Type | NumberOfPeople | *Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 211 | Entry Fee | 2 | F |
| 1001 | 212 | Camping Fee | 2 | T |
| 1002 | 361 | Entry Fee | 4 | T |
| 1003 | 388 | Entry Fee | 2 | F |
| 1003 | 389 | Entry Fee | 2 | F |
| 1003 | 390 | Camping Fee | 2 | T |
| 1003 | 391 | Camping Fee | 2 | T |
| 1005 | 401 | Camping Fee | 2 | T |

The last column is what I am going to create, and have no good way to design the SQL query.

When an itinerary issued, the visitors paid for Entry Fee and/or Camping Fee. If Both camping and entry paid, then we should count "number of people" from the row of camping fee (mark T). If an itinerary only have entry or camping, then mark T

Further explanation:

1. Booking system had some bugs, so visitors may pay camping fee only and not buy entry ticket, e.g. 1005
2. Booking system has the ability to make group purchase and indicate visitor info separately. e.g. 1003: two couples made one transaction, paid for both entry and camping

For ItineraryID 1001, total no. of people is 2, for 1003 total no. of people is 4. then For the above example table, to produce a total number of visitors, `SUM(case when Type='Camping Fee' then NumberOfPeople else 0 end)  OVER (PARTITION BY ItineraryID, Type)` should be ok, just wondering is there any other robust way to do it?

And I am stuck at the flag column creation, the real table has over a million rows...

Comment: If you can write a query to calculate the last column, why not just leave it as a query and always calculate it, til you fix the bugs? (Calculating and storing in a table is a nuisance if things update, but can be useful for performance if data is static)

Comment: Seems to me like your life would get easier if you write a query that splits the table into a camping table and an entry table (i.e. subqueries WHERE type = x) that are grouped/counted etc..

Comment: @Caius Jard for over a million rows, save query as view will hit the performance issue. So have to save the flag to the table. And I could not figure out how to create this flag in a proper way.

Comment: Similar to Caius's suggestion and depending on where your performance issues lie you can create two temp tables... one temp table to store your Camping Fee Grouped Records and the other to store your Entry Fee Grouped records.  Next all you would need to do is join those two temp tables together by the ItineraryID.  At this point each table would be a one-to-one relationship and easier to work with to get what you want.  Also you can index your temp tables if needed.

Comment: It really depends on how the view is queried, you can't just say "the table has a million rows, it has to persist the value". If the 99% use case was querying a specific itineraryID which is indexed then the query would be fast; the grouping considers eg 6 rows out of the million, sums it to 1 row, joins it to 6 rows. If you're querying all million rows several times a day then sure, persist the data. If you're amending 100,000 bookings 10 times a day, perhaps you should calc it rather than update a million rows a day...

Comment: @CaiusJard yep, sorry I got my mindset, should say the BI logic is to produce descriptive figures for the dashboard, e.g. total number of visitors by year/quarter/month, percentage of campsite occupied on each day/month, run prediction model for time series analysis based on number of visitors each months over  last 10 years data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
WITH tots AS(
  SELECT 
    itineraryID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Entry Fee' THEN NumberOfPeople END) as E,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Camping Fee' THEN NumberOfPeople END) as C
  FROM
    t
  GROUP BY itineraryID
)
```

If we join this back to our table (`SELECT * FROM t JOIN tots ON t.itineraryID = tots.itineraryID`) then we can use the E and C values per row to work some things out:

- If E or C is 0 then mark T ("If an itinerary only have entry or camping, then mark T")
- If E = C and it's a Camping row then mark 'T'
- If E = C and it's an Entry row mark 'F'

After this logic is done in a SELECT CASE WHEN, you just need to convert it to an UPDATE JOIN where you modify `t` (`UPDATE t SET flag = CASE WHEN ... FROM t JOIN tots ...`)

Or you can make a new table with the result of the select (or you can make a view this it and just query it and it will work out the T/F dynamically each time)

---

NB: Your example data didn't seem to consider what happens if 2 entry and 4 camping are bought.. But it's easy to extend the logic

Comment: Thanks Caius, I will try to play with your example query. In regards to "2 entry and 4 camping", the agreed calculation rule from management is to count the row of "camping fee" only. e.g. extend the 1003 with another 2 rows of "camping fee", then total number of visitors is 8

Comment: For those rows then you could maybe have "if it's an Entry row and C > E then put a flag of CONCAT('X', C - E)" so it gets an X2 flag, meaning you have to extend the entry rows by another 2.. They would be easy to look for with a `WHERE flag like` as a one time patch up op, or you can use a cross product to generate the same number of rows as is present after the X (have something like `WITH multiplier AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('X1'),('X2'),('X2'),('X3'),('X3'),('X3'))t)` - if you inner join this it will cause all X2 rows to double, X3 rows to triple.. because of the repetitions in VALUES)